# instagram get tag-name error with jquery

Tags: jquery, api, get, instagram

I'm doing a Client Side Auth. through `Instagram` `API`. 
Once I got the `access` `token`, I try to do a really simple `get` `request` building it like this :

```
var tag,  //insert from input text
    access_token = "myaccesstoken",
    url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + tag + "/media/recent?access_token"+myaccesstoken

$.get(url, {}, function(data) { console.log(data) } );
```

The problem is that the `get` `request` never works. Inspecting the network it is marked in red and `canceled`. 
If I write the complete `url` in the browser, I get the right `response`. Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres what works for me in my use of the instagram API:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    function docallUserlookup() {
        var tag='football';

            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE',
                dataType : 'jsonp',
                success : function(jsonData) {  


                    //to test it out and see a bit of the returned data, 
                    //lets show the users full name in the console...
                    console.log('found data for: ' + jsonData.data[0].user.username);

                    //... and append it to body
                    $('#mainDiv').html(jsonData.data[0].user.username);

                },
                error : function() {
                    alert('Problem getting Instagram users data! Try again.');
                }
            });
    };


docallUserlookup();

});
```

Playing around with the api via APIGEE.com helped a lot when I stared using it.  (hope its ok to mention that url / site here and that it doesnt violate any terms).

Comment: the problem was exactly the `dataType` (I discovered yesterday night, but Upvote anyway) that must be set to `jsonp`